# Reading countries names from JSON file problem

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I am trying to load and parse countries names from json file using swift but I can't

This is file's format which I try to read: [Countries JSON File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbPuG.png)

My code to do this task:

```
func getJsonFromUrl(){
    let url = NSURL(string: COUNTRIES_URL)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            if let countries_array = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "name") as? NSArray {
                for country in countries_array {
                    if let countryDict = country as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = countryDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                            self.countries_names.append((name as? String)!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                self.showNames()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

But when I run it, it gives me an error in this line:  `if let countries_array = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "name") as? NSArray {`
because of an unexpected nil.

Comment: Your line ```if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary { ``` should be ```as? Array<[String: Any]>``` because the topmost object is actually an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON starts with a bracket (`[`) therefore the root object is an array

Don't use `NSURL`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` and `value(forKey` in Swift.

And handle possible errors.

```
func getJsonFromUrl() {
    let url = URL(string: COUNTRIES_URL)!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        do {
            if let countriesArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:String]] {
                for country in countriesArray {
                    self.countries_names.append(country["name"]!)
                }
            }
        } catch { print(error) }
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
            self.showNames()
        })
    }).resume()
}
```

Or much more convenient with `Decodable`

```
struct Country : Decodable {
    let name : String
}

func getJsonFromUrl() {
    let url = URL(string: COUNTRIES_URL)!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        do {
            let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data!)
            self.countries_names = countries.map{$0.name}
        } catch { print(error) }
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
            self.showNames()
        })
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Also try not to use force unwrapping

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Everything is pretty safe in this case. The URL string is a constant, `data` is valid if `error` is `nil` and the JSON is consistent. You could even force unwrap the downcast to `[[String:String]]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an array not dictionary you need

```
if let dat = data {
   if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dat, options:[]) as? [[String:String]]{
   jsonObj.forEach { print($0["name"]) }    
}
```

or use `Codable`

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([[String:String]].self,from:data)
```

or with model

```
struct Root: Codable {
  let name : String
}

let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
```